# How to remove the key name in JsonObject?

Tags: android, json, custom-lists

I have this JsonObject below :

```
[
 {"ContactNumber":"+91 98765 12345"},
 {"ContactNumber":"+91 123 456 7890"}
]
```

Since "ContactNumber" is repeating..If i have 5000 contacts,it will repeat..So I need to remove the key-name "ContactNumber" in jsonObject such that new JsonObject will look like this :

```
"contacts" : [ 
   "+911234567890",
   "+911234567890",
   "+911234567890",
   "+911234567890",
   "+911234567890"
    ]
```

Actually i am trying to convert the Custom list to JsonObject ..Here its my code snippet

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String data = gson.toJson(reqContacts); // reqContacts is Custom list
JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonParser().parse(data).getAsJsonArray();
```

Comment: Is this in the scope of Javascript? Where are you running this?

Comment: try `public class Contacts { private ArrayList<String> contacts;
    public void setContacts(ArrayList<String> contacts) {
        this.contacts = contacts;}}` then  `ArrayList<String> listcontacts = new ArrayList<>();
        listcontacts.add("+911234567890");
        Contacts contacts = new Contacts();
        contacts.setContacts(listcontacts);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = new Gson().toJson(contacts);`

Comment: thanks..@Raghunandan i got json in desired format as i mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
    try {
        String data = "[{\"ContactNumber\":\"+91 98765 12345\"}, " +
                "{\"ContactNumber\":\"+91 123 456 7890\"}]";
        JSONArray arr1 = new JSONArray();
        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(data);
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
            arr1.put(obj.getString("ContactNumber"));
        }
        JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
        result.put("contacts", arr1);
        System.out.println(""+result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
try {
    // jsonString is a string variable that holds the JSON 
    JSONArray itemArray=new JSONArray(jsonString);
    for (int i = 0; i < itemArray.length(); i++) {
        int value=itemArray.getInt(i);
        Log.e("json", i+"="+value);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: no its not working..Actually i want to the store like this ... JsonArray jsonArray = {""contacts" : [ 
   "+911234567890",
   "+911234567890",
   "+911234567890",
   "+911234567890",
   "+911234567890"
    ]"};please look up the desired format

Answer (score 0):

Simply write `Object.values(myJsonObject)` where `myJsonObject` is the Json whose values you want to extract. This will return an array of the values, without the keys.

To store these as a Json Array, you can construct the new array viz

`{'contacts': Object.values(myJsonObject)}`